# Do all SMSC have an IP and port?

Tags: android, connection, smpp, service-provider

As I have only worked on SMSC Simulators, I had a general question regarding connections. In the real word, how do service providers connect to an SMSC? Is it through the same IP and port method? Or are there different ways to connect to an SMSC (like using a phone number assigned to the SMSC?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're connecting to an SMPP SMSC, you have to specify the server you are connecting to, and you can only do it by using either an IP address or a host name (a domain name.)

Depending on the type of service you're using and how your provider is set up, sometimes maybe the phone number you're assigned could be used as a login name or something but there are no hard rules for that.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Just needed to clarify that :)

Answer (score 0):

By using SMPP to connect to the SMSC you'll always use an ip and a port.
Some operators have a middleware(SMSHUB) in front of their SMSC that can offer you other methods of communication besides smpp; for instance webservices(https)